# SQL Query returning multiple Duplicate Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

scenario : I have Three Tables(Prisoners,AddPaymentTransaction,WithdrawPaymentTransation)
Date in Tables : i have 1 row of prisoner with PrisonerID=5 and two rows in both other table,
i have wrote query to return there data if any prisoner have add some payment in there account or with draw any payment from there payment on same day or on different dates etc.

here is my query :

```
select  at.PrisonerID ,at.Amount as AAmount,at.Date as ADate,wt.Amount as WAmount,wt.Date as WDate 
from Prisoners p, AddPaymentTransaction at,WithdrawPaymentTransation wt 
where p.PrisonerID=at.PrisonerID and p.PrisonerID=wt.PrisonerID and at.PrisonerID=wt.PrisonerID and at.PrisonerID=5
```

but it gives me 4 rows, 9 rows when i have 3 rows of data in each Table etc.
i want rows of data with out duplicate. any suggestions or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which database are you using, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Your style of JOIN is something like 20 years outdated, you should learn to use explicit joins like in Linger's answer below

Comment: Thanks for suggestion as i am new to Database so i am using simple Queries but soon will use like these queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `at.PrisonerID = wt.PrisonerID` in your query might be what is causing all of the duplicates.  I am guessing `AddPaymentTransaction` and `WithdrawPaymentTransation` should not be linked together.  So, how about the following:

```
SELECT at.PrisonerID, at.Amount as AAmount, at.Date as ADate,
       wt.Amount as WAmount, wt.Date as WDate 
FROM Prisoners p 
INNER JOIN AddPaymentTransaction at p.PrisonerID = at.PrisonerID 
INNER JOIN WithdrawPaymentTransation wt ON p.PrisonerID = wt.PrisonerID
WHERE at.PrisonerID = 5
```

but this probably isn't going to give you exactly what you are looking for either.  So maybe something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT p.PrisonerID, 'AddPayment' AS Type, 
         apt.Amount as TransAmount, apt.Date AS TransDate
  FROM Prisoners p 
  INNER JOIN AddPaymentTransaction apt ON p.PrisonerID = apt.PrisonerID 
  WHERE apt.PrisonerID = 5

  UNION

  SELECT p.PrisonerID, 'WithdrawPayment' AS Type, 
         wt.Amount as TransAmount, wt.Date as TransDate 
  FROM Prisoners p 
  INNER JOIN WithdrawPaymentTransation wt ON p.PrisonerID = wt.PrisonerID
  WHERE wt.PrisonerID = 5
) AS mq
ORDER BY mq.TransDate DESC
```

Comment: ***@Saeed Khan***, just curious which query did you go with?